# Is it possible to upgrade IOS project from Cocos2d-x v2.1.4 to v2.2.6

Tags: cocos2d-x

My game was written in C++ cocos2d-x v2.1.4 years ago.
However, according to Apple, beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support.

As Cocos2d-x v2.2.6 support the 64 bit, I would like to upgrade my cocos2d-x framework from 2.1.4 to 2.2.6.

If it is possible, please kindly provide me some steps in doing so. Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? So your question should be: "How to upgrade .. ?". Which I find too broad for SO. The basic process is: remove old cocos2d, move new cocos2d in place, fix the xcode project (add new cocos2d files, remove missing cocos2d files), then fix any API changes.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D
Can you please suggest me on how to upgrade the framework?

1) Should I create a new project as Cocos2d-x v2.2.6 then copy paste in my resources and codes.

OR 

2) Should I patch my cocos2d-x 2.2.6 in to 2.1.4? (I tried this but I don't think it run as cocos2d-x 2.2.6, I think I did it incorrectly.. maybe..)

As you suggested, I should go for the second option. Can you please clarify more on how to patch the files. Thank you :)

Comment: 1) should work best/easiest

Comment: @LearnCocos2D
Thanky you..
I got one more question, as we know that beginning on Feb 15,2015 new IOS apps must include 64-bit support.


I am not quite sure whether my game include 64-bit support.
But they can run on iPhone 5s 6 6+.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D
This is my build setting on my project:
Architectures: Standard archietecture (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
Valid Architectures: armv7 armv7s i386

This is my cocos2d build setting:
Architectures: $(ARCH_STANDARD_32_BIT) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
Valid Architecture: armv7 armv7s arm64

My deployment target : 5.1.1

Cocos2d-x 2.1.4

will these setting be eligible for Feb 15 2015. I would like to make sure first whether my app is eligible.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible and it is an easy task :)
You just have to create new cocos 2.2.6 project and move resources from the 2.1.4 version project. Next setup icons, splashscreen and others and compile.
As far as I remember the only minor change in API is change from:

```
object.numberOfRunningActions()
```

to

```
object.getNumberOfRunningActions()
```

Comment: @sortis I would like to vote, but it says right here that "Vote up requires 15 reputation". I'm kind of new to stack overflow. Sorry :(